# Color sharps in key signature with lilypond

Tags: lilypond

Is it possible to color the sharps (or flats) in a key signature using lilypond?

Notes can be individually colored:

```
\version "2.22.2"

\score {
  \relative {
 \key a \major 
 \omit Score.TimeSignature
 a b
 \override NoteHead #'color = #red
 cis  
  }
}
```

[image: colored note]

How about sharps in the key signature?

[image]

Comment: I think that if your goal is to create instructional music, it would be clearer to have arrows pointing at the items you're trying to emphasise. If a music symbol is coloured then you have to read it *twice* - first time to get the colour which has some significance that you're trying to emphasise, and a second time for its actual musical significance ("third sharp in the key signature is G#" or "don't forget to play me as C# rather than C natural"

Comment: I think it depends on context.  In this case the examples will be close together with multiple key signatures, so arrows might clutter it.  Below I've found a solution, not sure if the best one but it works.

Answer (score 4):

```
% Functions
prepare =  
{\omit Score.TimeSignature
 \omit Score.BarLine
 \omit NoteHead
}

color_it = \once \override Accidental.color = red
end_it = {g g \undo \omit Score.BarLine \bar "||"}

\score {
  \relative {\prepare 
    fis''1
    \color_it
    cis
    \end_it
  }
}
```

[image]